# How to integrate Keras Callbacks and History plotting functionality within a Python function?

Tags: python, function, tensorflow, keras

I have built a model fitting function (shown below) which is used by a few other Python functions to calculate RMSE (evaluation metrics), and it works fine at the moment.

However, I would like to also implement two other aspects to the following code. First, I want to be able to plot Loss curves for Train and Validation datasets (which is typically returned as a History Object by the model.fit function shown in the code). Second, I want to implement Tensorboard callbacks to the **model.fit** function as well.

The challenge I'm facing now is that, I'm not sure how these extra functionalities can be implemented to the below code, or perhaps within this code.

I tried returning history, using the following code (which was inside the main Python function shown below):

```
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_split=0.3, epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=1)
'''
'''
     return model, history
```

But, because 'History' is returned as an object within the main function, I'm not able to use this object anywhere outside the function to plot the Loss plot curves.

```
# Python Function
def model_fit(train, config):
    
    # Prepare data
    data = series_to_supervised(train, n_input)
    train_x, train_y = data[:, :-1], data[:, -1]
    train_x = train_x.reshape((train_x.shape[0], n_seq, n_steps, 1))
    
    # Define Model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=n_kernel, activation='relu', input_shape=(None,n_steps,1))))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=n_kernel, activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(n_nodes, activation='relu')))
    model.add(Dense(n_nodes, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
    
    # Fit Model
    model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_split=0.3, epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=1)
    return model
```

Could I achieve all these from within a Python function as shown, and how ? Or would I need to actually just write the entire neural network not as a function, but as a stand alone executable; so that I can use History object and utilise all Keras Callbacks ?

Could I execute this function and immediate have History objects and Keras Callbacks automatically having returned ?

Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by this: _But, because 'History' is returned as an object within the main function, I'm not able to use this object anywhere outside the function to plot the Loss plot curves._

Comment: @NicolasGervais I meant to say that, model.fit would return a History callback. Since the model.fit happens to be within the main function, I am not able to call History without calling the main function.

Comment: just save this history object? return it fro mthe function

Answer (score 0):

I have taken out the details from the Python function and instead carried out the implementation as a stand alone script (just to be able to return History object and to visualise the plots).

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from datetime import datetime
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping

class TimingCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, logs={}):
        self.logs=[]
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.starttime = timer()
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.logs.append(timer()-self.starttime)

# unpack config
n_seq, n_steps, n_filters, n_kernel, n_nodes, n_epochs, n_batch = config
n_input = n_seq * n_steps

# prepare data
data = series_to_supervised(train, n_input)
train_x, train_y = data[:, :-1], data[:, -1]
train_x = train_x.reshape((train_x.shape[0], n_seq, n_steps, 1))

# simple early stopping
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=0, patience=60, min_delta=1)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('Asset_5_best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

# Define Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=n_kernel, activation='relu', input_shape=(None,n_steps,1))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=n_kernel, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(n_nodes, activation='relu')))
model.add(Dense(n_nodes, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])

# Fit Model
time = TimingCallback()
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_split=0.3, epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=1, callbacks=[es, mc, time])
```

Comment: At the moment this script is working as I expect. I would welcome other solutions if there's any.